# Ldap with cloud application

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, ldap, cloud, adfs

I was wondering if you guys could help me, I'm trying to use ldap to connect with our AD but the settings on the cloud app seem to fail.

How do you set up ldap with external servers? Is there some config that needs done on our DC? Do we need to use ADFS? Could the firewall be causing issues?

I'm a bit lost with this one, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Without more details this is difficult to answer.  There are myriad ways to connect to an LDAP server.  Validate that the connection URI is correct for the platform that you're using.  Also, if you believe a firewall issue to be at fault, check this port list against your open ports.

[Active Directory and Active Directory Domain Services Port Requirements](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723(v=ws.10).aspx)